# Using slice! on a variable is modifying the node attribute that populated the variable

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

In OpsWorks Stacks, I have set a layer attribute using the custom JSON field:

```
{
  "layer_apps" : [
    "app_manager"
  ]
}
```

The `app_` portion of the attribute is necessary for the workflow. At times, I need to temporarily remove the `app_` portion within a cookbook. To do this, I use `slice!`:

```rb
node['layer_apps'].each do |app_name|

  install_certs_app_name = app_name
  install_certs_app_name.slice!('app_') # 'app_manager' => 'manager'
  # snip
end
```

However, once this is done, even though `app_name` isn't being directly modified, each `node['layer_apps']` attribute gets sliced, which carries on to subsequent cookbooks and causes failures. The behaviour I expected was that `slice!` would modify `app_name`, and not the current `node['layer_apps']` attribute. Thinking that `app_name` was a link to the attribute rather than being it's own variable, I tried assigning its value to a separate variable (`install_certs_app_name` and similar in other cookbooks), but the behaviour persisted.

Is this expected behaviour in Ruby/Chef? Is there a better way to be excluding the `app_` prefix from the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app_name` *is* being directly modified. That's the reason for the bang `!` after the method... so that you're aware that the method mutates the object.

and `app_name` and `install_certs_app_name` are referencing the same object.

Note that `slice` and `slice!` both return "app_" but the bang object mutates the caller by removing the sliced text.

If you did

result = install_certs_app_name.slice!('app_') 
puts result
==> app_
puts install_certs_app_name
--> manager

Try (instead)

```
  install_certs_app_name = app_name.dup
  install_certs_app_name.slice!('app_')
```

So you have two separate objects.

Alternatively,

```
  install_certs_app_name = app_name.sub('app_', '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @SteveTurczyn!

I did try `install_certs_app_name = app_name.slice('app_')` in the past, but oddly, ruby seems to return the portion of the string that was removed, not the resulting string. I haven't seen `.dup` before, though, so I'll give that a try.

Comment: Yes, I had my head in the clouds.. `slice` and `slice!` always return the sliced text  so  `string = 'abc' ; result = string.slice('a')` and `string = 'abc'; result = string.slice!('a')` in both cases `result`will have "a" but in the second example the object in `string` is modified.

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd want a variable sliced, what you'll is the non-destructive version:

`str.slice` and not `str.slice!`

These are often referred to as Bang-methods, and replace the variable in place.
Below is an example with the `.downcase` method. This is the same principle for `.slice`.

EDIT:
However, since `.slice` returns the part that's been cut out, you could just remove the `app_`-part `.sub` like

`"app_manager".sub("app_",'') #=> "manager"`

- http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/objects/bangs.html
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice

Comment: Thanks! I did try the non-destructive methods, but slice specifically seems to return the part of the string that gets removed, not the string that remains. Is there a proper way to have the non-destructive slice return the resulting string?

Comment: Oh right, let me just update my answer with another option.

Comment: It does! Steve's answer got the check mark because I tried his first and it works for my purposes, but yours seems to be more elegant. Is it a SO faux-pas to change the accepted answer?

Comment: No need to change it - I'm not here entirely for reputation ;) And since his will work as well it's cool, albeit dupping a string to slice the original seems a bit weird.

Comment: "In case you'd want a variable sliced" – You can't slice a variable. Variables aren't objects in Ruby, and you can only call methods on objects. There are exactly two things you can do with a variable, and slicing is not one of them: assign a variable and dereference a variable. "These are often referred to as Bang-methods, and replace the variable in place." – Bang-methods simply mean that there is a pair of methods that perform similar operations, but one is more surprising than the other. And it does *not* replace the variable in-place. It mutates the object that is referenced by the …

Comment: … variable. If it were changing the variable, then the OP's code would have worked, because the mistake in his code is *precisely* that he believes that the `slice!` method changes the variable as opposed to the object.

Answer (score 1):

When you assigning `app_name` to `install_certs_app_name` you still referencing to the same object. In order to create new object you can do:

```
install_certs_app_name = app_name.dup
```

New object with the same value is created. And slicing `install_certs_app_name` does not affect `app_name` this way.